# How do i make ImageView Float half outside of the Cardview in android?

Tags: android, xml

I am facing a problem with my cardview layout in android. ***I have an ImageView and TextView inside card but i want to make Imageview float a little outside of it with Negative Margins but ImageView gets cut off.***

I have looked up to internet for the solution but nothing seems to work out.

Sharing my XML code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".cardlistitem">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="50dp"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:background="@drawable/numbersbackground">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:src="@drawable/numbersicon"
                android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
                android:elevation="100dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Numbers"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

  </LinearLayout>
```

[image: Layout Image]